# Why is Scanner slower than BufferedReader when reading from input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I understand what is Scanner good for, and also when to use Scanner and when BufferedReader.
I read a different, yet in some therm similar question [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader)

**Why is Scanner so slow when I read from the input?**
I assume it has to do with that there is a small buffer in Scanner, but here I am lost.
The original problem is from,  [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/INTEST) , but I am not interested in that solution.

Here is a code example with a given input:
Input:

- 7 3
- 1
- 51
- 966369
- 7
- 9
- 999996
- 1

And the code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String[] s = br.readLine().split(" "); 
        int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int divideNumber = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
            String number = br.readLine();
            if (number.length() < 11) {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                if (num % divideNumber == 0) {
                    count++;
                }
            } 
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

If I read the same code with scanner it is slow.

Comment: [`Scanner`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.hasNextLine%28%29) is based on regular expression parsing, [`BufferedReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/io/BufferedReader.java#BufferedReader.readLine%28boolean%29) does simple checks on `char`s

Comment: If you want to get a really fast solution to that problem you would btw have to skip `BufferedReader` & `Integer.parseInt()` completely. It's still creating an unnecessary temporary `String` object before you can convert it into an `int` and that takes a lot of time compared to building `int` directly from the stream.

Comment: I came here because I was having to read a CSV file with ~13M lines. Used Scanner first and it took well over 2 hours. Changed to BufferedReader and it took a few minutes. On a modern MacBook Pro. I understood that there would be speed differences but that they were so big baffled me. EDIT: Second time running directly afterwards it took only a few seconds. Maybe the JIT is kicking in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upper-level classes/methods are generally slower than lower-level classes/methods.
In the same way you could ask why is searching with `regular expressions` slower than
searching with `String.indexOf()`. Actually I've seen such questions here on SO.

The more specialized your class/method is, the better it can perform.
It does e.g. just 1 simple thing but does it quickly and efficiently.
More general classes/methods do e.g. 10-20 different things, so they
are more powerful but due to this they are slower.

I am speaking in general here, I haven't compared `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` myself.

Answer (score 3):

Beside what has been already said Scanner focus is being a Swiss army knife, it is quite more complex and in simple cases covered by BufferedReader that extra gadgets burden it. It's like sending an aircraft carrier to kill a rat.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner inbuilt functions parse the tokens where the BufferedReader just read the input.There is overhead of parsing tokens...

Comment: This is true, but If I read the example code whit Scanner the token would be the whole line, according to the documentation:

"A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods."

Comment: So it is only so slow because it needs that extra action for a token?

Comment: Check this [link](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2009/2/Difference-Scanner-Method-Buffered.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question where you state a different question. The scanner performs extra tasks such as parsing integers and characters. The buffered reader reads raw input. What it reads is what it gives.

Hope I helped,

Jarod

Comment: I thought it **can** parse primitive types and strings, which means it doesn't do all action, just what is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Some highly voted hints why Scanner is slower can be found in [Scanner vs. BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader).

This performance difference may be critical in some cases like competitive programming.
Therefore Codeforces has numerous posts with custom faster input parsers like [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7018), [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/21125) (with benchmark) and [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/6834?#comment-124499).