# Java Multiple Input in a Single row

Tags: java, input, row

Enter any number of integer values in a single row separated by space and the calculate and print the sum to next line.

EX:   input: 1 2 3 4
     output: 10

Comment: `System.out.println(Stream.of("1 2 3 4".split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the whole line as a `String` and than split it into a String array and than you can add it one by one for this purpose as following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String s[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

for this you have to import :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

This is faster than `Scanner`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797573/why-is-scanner-slower-than-bufferedreader-when-reading-from-input) for more details about `Scanner` and `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Please avoid answering bad questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help The worked properly i got the solution. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I tried to do it with scanner but don't work. Here is the code:


import java.util.*;
class Multi
{
 public static void main(String args[])Throws IOException
{
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s[] = sc.next().split(" ");
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
     {
           
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
 
}
}

Comment: and post your above code in question by editing it. I will try to debug :) @λττιτυδερπιηζε

Answer (score 3):

This should work - console.hasNext uses whitespace as its delimiter.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
while (console.hasNext()) {
    sum += console.nextInt();
}
System.out.print(sum);
```