# How to create a fixed size IntArray and initializing the array later in Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, collections

I can't figure out a way to add values to an array in Kotlin .

I want to get values from user and add them to the array.

```
val arr = arrayOf<Int>()
```

or

```
var arr = intArrayOf()
```

In Java I would do something like this:

```
Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
int arr[] = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i]=ob.nextInt();
}
```

How can I do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin)

Comment: @MichaelEaster I'd like to say there is no duplications.

Comment: See also [Reading console input in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283393/reading-console-input-in-kotlin/41283570#41283570) with ready-to-use functions for reading arrays

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to [escape](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin) the static field `in` of `System` class with backtick (**`**), since `in` is a keyword in Kotlin. for example:

```
val ob = Scanner(System.`in`)
```

You can create a fixed size `int[]` array without initializing it immediately in Kotlin, then the default value of the elements in array are `0`. for example:

```
val arr = IntArray(5) // create IntArray via constructor
```

There is a bit different for using `for-loop` in Kotlin, for example:

```
for(i in 0 until arr.size){
    arr[i] = ob.nextInt();
}
```

**OR** initializing an `int[]` array during creation, for example:

```
val arr = IntArray(5){ ob.nextInt() }
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have fixed sizes. When creating an array, you will have to declare it's size during initialization.

```
val arr: IntArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
val arr = Array (3){it}
```

If you want to create a collection that you can dynamically add values to, then you can create a mutable list.

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
list.add(1)
list.add(2)
list.add(3)
```