# Input string & Int in the same line kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I input a String and an int in the same line? how do i make n an Int?

`val (s, n) = readln().split(" ")`

Sample Input

> Hello 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading console input in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283393/reading-console-input-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

I would split it in two lines. For example:

```
val (s, _n) = readln().split(" ")
val n = _n.toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val (s, n) = with(readln().split(" ")) { this[0] to this[1].toInt() }
```

Comment: Add some expaination on why this is the solution. What you changed etc.