# Trouble receiving data to C socket client from Java socket server

Tags: java, c, sockets

My Socket client is written in C and sends the values in the format below:

```
x00\x2C\x02\x00\xE0\x00
```

Now I would like to read the hex values from the TCP/IP socket server which is written in Java.

What should be a approach to read the stream values in Java Socket?

I'm trying to read in the following way, but it does not work:

```
InputStream ins = sock.getInputStream();
int byteRead;

while((byteRead = ins.read()) != -1) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(byteRead & 0xFF));
}
```

Comment: Look at `Socket` in (and out) streams. The data as it is transmitted over the networks is always binary, so it only depends how you interpret it on receiving end.

Comment: Tried to read as shown in original post.

Comment: The 'format below' is literally that, a 'format'. The data is still binary. It is six bytes, value `0x002C0200E000.` You can read that with `DataInputStream.readShort()/.readInt()`.

Comment: You can use Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16) , as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834468/java-reading-hex-values-into-an-array-of-type-int

Comment: Do you mean that the sender is literally sending a String containing hex representations? In this case you should be converting a String to integer, not other way around.

Comment: "It does not work" can be anything. Is there any output at standard output? What does it look like?

Comment: Sender is sending string containing hex representation "\x00\x2C\x02\x00\xE0\x00". From java server side, trying to read as DataInputStream.getBytes but it is printing some strange characters with square shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First stating the obvious, "\x41" is one byte with hex 41 aka ASCII 'A'. C strings also have a terminating `\x00` following it.
So you are writing

```
\x00\x2C\x02\x00\xE0\x00
```

as char array with size 6. Writing it as string would write an empty string, as the first byte is `\x00`.

On the java side there is no problem with `\x00`, that is just a regular byte/char.

The java code is okay. A variation might be:

```
try (InputStream ins = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream())) {
    int byteRead;
    while ((byteRead = ins.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.printf("%02X%n", byteRead & 0xFF);
    }
} // Closes
```

Here capital X causes capitalized hex, and %n a line break. `String.format` would be the alternative.

My first guess would be that the C writing is erroneously done with `puts`, using `strlen` or so.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Print formatting was the clue to resolve our problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the length of the message you will need to read each byte reperesentation into a String buffer and use [Byte#parseByte(buffer, 16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte-java.lang.String-int-) to make a **signed** byte *[-127, 127]* out of it.

If you know the length of the whole String that the client is sending you could read it all and then [String#split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) it using a delimiter whicht seems to be in your case `\x`. and again make use of `Byte#parseByte(buffer, 16)` to convert.

If you need **unsigned** values *[0, 255]* then you have to go with [Integer.html#parseInt(buffer, 16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-).